# Determine whether the statement is true or false

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Determine whether the statement is true or false. Explain your answer.
>   $(i)$ If $y=x^2$ is a contour of $f$, then $f_x(0,0)=0$.
>   $(ii)$ If the displacement vector from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$ is a positive multiple of $\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$, then $f(x_0,y_0)\leq f(x_1,y_1)$

$(i)$ What I mean contour is a level curve $f(x,y)=c$ of $f$. Hence $y-x^2=0\implies f(x,y)=y-x^2$. Hence $f_x=-2x$ which is $0$ at $(0,0)$. Hence $(i)$ is true. **Is my approach is correct$?$**
$(ii)$ displacement vector,$d=⟨x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0⟩$. Then $d=\lambda \nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ where $\lambda>0$. Now **how to conclude any information of $f(x_0,y_0)\leq f(x_1,y_1)?$**

Comment: First, what are your requirements for $f$? $f_x(0,0)$ or the gradient might not exist for just "any" $f$.

Hint for (i): Your approach is not correct, as your determination of $f$ is unfounded. $y=x^2$ is also a contour of $f(x,y)=y-x^2+17$, $f(x,y)=y^2-2yx^2+x^4-13$, a.s.o.
Hint for (ii): Think about the one-dimensional case, where the 'gradient' is just the derivative and if it is positive the function will (locally) increase with increasing argument, and if it is negative the funtion will (locally) increase with decreasing argument. Is that still true if you remove "locally"?

Comment: @Ingix $(ii)$for dimensional case, I think it is still true if I remove "locally" but multivarible case the gredient is the unique vector field which projection to any direction give directional derivative(like one dimension case:derivative). here If I somehow conclude that directional derivative then maybe I will get my answer.But how$?$ And If you don't mind then can you give a complete solution of $(i)$ please

Comment: Main problem: I don't know the solution to (i) :-( For (ii): The answer is negative, you can't remove "locally" and have it stay correct, both in one and 2 dimensions. For one dimension, take $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $x_0=\pi/4$ and $x_1=\pi$. $f(x)$ is increasing at $x_0$, so $x_1$ is in 'the right directiont' from $x_0$, but still $0=f(x_1) < \sqrt{2}/2 = f(x_0)$.